# Hide Scrollbar IFRAME 100%

Tags: html, iframe

first of all, I have read all the related topics created and none has worked for me.

I have this iframe 100% of the width and height of the screen

```json
<iframe src="https://site.test" frameborder="0" id="iframe" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; border: none; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;"></iframe>
```

I tried this and it doesn't work for me

```
iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```

But it does not work. Be careful, I need to hide them, not disable them, so
`scrolling ="no"`

It does not serve me.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your code. remove display:block in inline css.

Comment: I tried without it too but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

how to?

```css
a {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#iframe{
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Well, apparently, from https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/display-iframe-contents-without-scrollbars/ : "In essence, the child document is telling the parent how to display it. If you want it the other way around, you have to apply the rules dynamically via scripting". Try the script in the first part of the guide

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the iframe then use these line of codes inside the `iframe` page CSS:

```
/* Works for Chrome */
::-webkit-scrollbar{width:0}
```

And

```
/* For Firefox and Microsoft Edge or IE */
html{scrollbar-width:none;-ms-overflow-style:none;}
```